# Why can't I update this mapping in my burn function?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I am trying to update a mapping of the owner's token count when the owner burns a token.

mapping (address => uint) public ownerTokenCount; //# of tokens in wallet

It gets updated here:

```
_mintToken(owner) {

userTokenCount(owner) = userTokenCount(owner) + 1

_mint;

}
```

It should update again here but it is not.

```
_burntoken(owner){

(require userTokenCount(owner) >0); // this throws

userTokenCount(owner) = userTokenCount(owner) - 1;

_burn;

}
```

Comment: Show the full text of the smart contract and explain what exactly is not working. What you have shown does not match the Solidity syntax

Comment: Hi DabblinDantheDino! Please include a minimal compilable example that causes the problem. It is likely the error is in another part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a map you need to use []

For example:

```
function _burntoken(address owner) private {

    require (userTokenCount[owner] > 0);

    userTokenCount[owner] = userTokenCount[owner] - 1;

    _burn();

}
```